# Look for certain words in a Pandas Dataframe column and if found, add them to a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file with 2 columns: "`Title`", "`Ingredients`", and a list of words: ["`peanut butter, chocolate chip, pizza, ice cream, sweet potato, crock pot, steak, pan cake, green beans, cream cheese, pork chop`"]. I need to look for these words in the "`Ingredients`" column and if any of the words from the list are found in it, they will be added to a new column: "`Categories`" in that specific row. For example: If "`Ingredients`" `= ice cream, pizza, chicken`; then "`Categories`" `= ice cream, pizza` (since `chicken` is not in our list). I am a beginner to Pandas and have searched the internet for possible solutions but was not successful. I have also tried `df[df[''].str.contains())]` but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you need to add to category column if no value matches in the list??

Comment: Hi maverick,  good question. I apologize for forgetting to mention it. If nothing matches, I want to add N/A to the "Category" column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IICU

Data

```
   df2=pd.DataFrame({'Ingredients':['ice cream, pizza, chicken', 'peanut butter, chocolate chip, beey, pizza']})
    df2
```

Join all the strings in the list l

```
  l=['peanut butter', 'chocolate chip', 'pizza', 'ice cream', 'sweet potato', 'crock pot', 'steak', 'pan' 'cake', 'green' 'beans', 'cream' 'cheese', 'pork' 'chop']
    s='|'.join(l)
s
```

Apply str.findall

```
 df2['Categories']=df2.Ingredients.str.findall(s)
    df2
```

Can add if you want N/A

```
df2['Categories']=np.where(df2.Ingredients.str.match(s),df2['Categories'],'N/A')
df2
```

Outcome

[image]

Rerun after your comment

[image]

Comment: Did this help or you need more assistance?

Comment: It works perfectly. I need help with one more thing. How do I add N/A to the "Category" column if no value matches? Currently, it just adds "[]". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry was heldp, please see my edit if you want to add N/A

Comment: Does that help or not?

Comment: Hi, apologies for being late. I actually took care of N/A by using regular expression and replacing the [] with N/A. I know that it's a hack but it worked for me. I will check your solution and let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey. I have checked the new line of code that you provided. When I add this line at the end, it just replaces everything in the "Categories" column with N/A. If I put it before the other line, then there is not "Categories" column.

Comment: What version of pandas are you on? Ran it on 1.03 on different pcs and it ran fine and  it ran fine. See attached snip

Comment: I am on 1.0.1. I just found out that it's not a version problem but a problem with the format of my data. The "ingredients" you create in your data frame are shown as this: peanut butter, chocolate chip, beey, pizza; whereas in my "ingredients" from the CSV file are shown as this: ['ice cream', 'pizza', 'chicken']. Is there a way to get around this?